# Network monitoring script for Debian

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I have a question about a script I've found to monitor a device on my network.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="192.168.11.1"
COUNT=1


SUBJECT="Ping failed"
EMAILID="me@mydomain.com"
for myHost in $HOSTS
do
count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print     $1 }')
if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then

echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" $EMAILID
fi
done
```

Upon executing the script, it seems to work, but it doesn't send anything to the email address.
Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `mail` to `mailx`

Comment: That doesn't help me much. Using an older version of mail doesn't solve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your script as follows and try again.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="192.168.11.1"
COUNT=1
SUBJECT="Ping failed"
EMAILID="me@mydomain.com"

for myHost in $HOSTS
do

count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')

if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then

cd ~

if [ -s PING_FILE ]
then
rm PING_FILE 
fi

echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)" > PING_FILE
mail -s "$SUBJECT" $EMAILID < PING_FILE

#if you want to get the file itself use the below code #
mutt -s "$SUBJECT" -a PING_FILE - $EMAILID < PING_FILE

fi

done
```

Regards,

Dominic

Comment: I tried that and it still would not send the email. I feel like there is some sort of argument error starting at the grep command. I'm truly baffled..